# driver.windowHandles is unable to give child window id

Tags: selenium-webdriver

when i click on Link text,it will open new child window then i want pass inputs on 
 child window. i am able to open new child window but couldn't find child window html attributes even unable find child window id in **driver.windowHandles** ,it is always returning only Parent window id.

i tried with driver.WindowHandles.Last()

```
string lastwindow = driver.WindowHandles.Last();
driver.SwitchTo().Window(lastwindow);
```

i have tried with below code

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<string> window = driver.WindowHandles;
foreach (string strwindow in window)
{
if (!title.Equals(driver.Title))
{
 driver.SwitchTo().Window(strwindow);
}
else
{
driver.SwitchTo().Window(mainwindow);
}
}
```

Please anyone suggest me to get childwindow id and how to pass my inputs to child window.it is a great help for me.

Answer (score 0):

A few words about the solution for your problem:

1. Before you click to open child window, get the parent window handle & save it.
2. Switch to the child window.
3. Induce some wait for child window elements to render.
4. Perform other tasks on the child window.
5. Close the child window.
6. Switch back to parent window through the saved parent window handle.
7. Here is the prototype code for your reference:

   ```
   String parent_window = driver.getWindowHandle();
   System.out.println("Before switching Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("to_open_child_window")).click();
   Set<String> s1 = driver.getWindowHandles();
   Iterator<String> i1 = s1.iterator();
   while(i1.hasNext())
   {
       String child_window = i1.next();
       if (!parent_window.equalsIgnoreCase(child_window))
       {
           driver.switchTo().window(child_window);
           //induce some wait here for the elements to render
           System.out.println("After switching title is : "+driver.getTitle());
           //perform your other tasks
           driver.close();
       }
   }
   driver.switchTo().window(parent_window);
   System.out.println("Back to parent Window : "+driver.getTitle());
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.